# How do i get the pure object out of promise object when i do promise inside promise?

Tags: object, promise

here is what i get in browser console and the code. I need first promise "starships" to get an array of url links, then i need second promise for "movieURLs" to get an object from each of that link. But when i finish it all i always get a Promise object with a pure object inside it and i need that object to access it and cannot when its in that form.

Im doing it in React.

this is what i get in console:

1. *`(3) [Promise, Promise, Promise]`*

   1. **`0`**`: Promise`

      1. `[[Prototype]]: Promise`
      2. `[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"`
      3. `[[PromiseResult]]: Object`

         1. **`id`**`: 4`
         2. **`releaseDate`**`: "1977-05-25"`
         3. **`title`**`: "A New Hope"`
         4. `[[Prototype]]: Object`
   2. **`1`**`: Promise`

      1. `[[Prototype]]: Promise`
      2. `[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"`
      3. `[[PromiseResult]]: Object`

         1. **`id`**`: 6`
         2. **`releaseDate`**`: "1983-05-25"`
         3. **`title`**`: "Return of the Jedi"`
         4. `[[Prototype]]: Object`
   3. **`2`**`: Promise {<fulfilled>: {…}}`
   4. **`length`**`: 3`
   5. `[[Prototype]]: Array(0)`

My code:

```
 PromiseAll([getStarships(user)])
            .then((result) => result[0][starshipIndex].films)
            .then((movieUrls) =>
                movieUrls.map((movieUrl: any) =>
                    getMovies(movieUrl).then((data) => data[0]),
                ),
            )
            .then((movieList) => setMovies(movieList))
            .catch((error) => console.warn(error))
```

I tried to use .result or .response or .response.items, but i always get undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This results in a `Promise`:

```
getMovies(movieUrl).then((data) => data[0])
```

Which means this returns an array of `Promise` objects:

```
movieUrls.map((movieUrl: any) =>
  getMovies(movieUrl).then((data) => data[0]),
)
```

You can resolve those promises with a call to `Promise.all`, which would return a `Promise` that resolves to the array of results.  For example:

```
.then((movieUrls) =>
  Promise.all(movieUrls.map((movieUrl: any) =>
    getMovies(movieUrl).then((data) => data[0]),
  ))
)
```

In which case the next `.then()` callback would get the array of results, rather than the array of `Promise` objects.

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly.
my calss is called PromiseAll because it's an imported custom made module that works similarly to one you suggested.